# An error comes out when building in texmaker, "I can't find file `glyphtounicode-ntx.tex"

Tags: miktex, texmaker

[image]

After I click build in texmaker (PDFLaTeX) this error comes out. I have checked the path and I do have glyphtounicode-ntx.tex in there.

What should I do?

Also, I'm very new to this so I don't what additional information you need. If you need something, I'll give it as fast as possible.

Thanks for help

Comment: Show a complete minimal example that can be used for tests.

Comment: It's an error in the miktex package. Make a bug report: https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging. As a work around you can get the missing file from CTAN https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/pdfx

Comment: Hello, the code is provided by the local uni. It is the template for writing theses and thus is not short. How can I post the code? Thanks

Comment: I've also tried downloading the folder pdfx again from CTAN and replacing it in the appropriate folder. That didn't help either. 

I tried building a sample code I got from the internet: http://mally.stanford.edu/~sr/computing/latex-example.html and that build fine. Maybe it's a problem with the temple from my uni?

Comment: https://github.com/JDan04/TempleteFromUni.git

Comment: In such situations I would always test run in the default copy of TeXworks that comes with MiKTeX (and tex Live) Running your EN with a currently up-to-date MiKTeX only reports 1301 color profile which is expected as I don't have file TempleteEN.xmpdata  data (This is the source of the Texmaker error but *enter* in TeXworks will proceed with compilation) and line 135 \chapwithtoc{List of Abbreviations} (possibly due to other missing data?)

Comment: When I try it using Texworks the same problem occurs:

! I can't find file `glyphtounicode-ntx.tex'.
l.2354  \input glyphtounicode-ntx.tex
                                     
Please type another input file name:

Comment: Agreed after I add a dummy missing file I get the same message but until a fix is available *enter* will continue till next error (hence comment not answer)

Comment: As I already wrote: get the missing file from ctan http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/pdfx/glyphtounicode-ntx.tex. Put it e.g. in the folder of your document until miktex repairs the package.

Comment: I have the file there and had it there the whole time. I tried downloading the one from CTAN and replacing the old one. Didn't make a difference.